# cant move my object to correct position on scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi am using this code to try and move the object when triggered collision.

the following code seems to move the object off the scene to different x/y values.

The result I'm looking for is the object to move to the positions listed below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fairy : MonoBehaviour {
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //Debug.Log("Collision");

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "T")
    {

        collision.gameObject.transform.position =new  Vector3  (-2.51f,-2.56f,0f);
        Debug.Log("T Position is " + gameObject.transform.position);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `collision.gameObject.transform.position =new  Vector3  (-2.51f,-2.56f,0f);` will move **the object colliding into the object holding the script** to the **world space**, not the **local space** (position relative to its parent)

Comment: Thank you realised that new position changed depending on what angle I collide.  Thank you will need to read up then.  As not sure how to achieve position in local space

Comment: Use `collision.gameObject.transform.localPosition` to place the object relatively to parent

Comment: Thank you for reply. Need to do some reading then to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: So I want to use transform.translate??

Comment: Using `transform.translate` will move the object according to the current position according to its **local axes** (except if you provide [`Space.World`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.World.html) as second parameter).

Comment: Thank you my first project is a spelling game for my daughter.  I have a fairy that can be moved by mouse or  touch and collect the letters to make words.

Comment: Thank you will play with all methods later

Comment: solved collision.gameObject.transform.localPosition  works